# Save/Use images without allocating 300mb memory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, image, memory

I am building a windows project in .net 4.0 c#.

I am now saving images to hard drive, and that's not taking any memory at all because i am only loading the image once i want to view it. But now i need to remove the creating of images in hard drive and create it some other way. Like creating a memory stream and save it to an object and serialize it down to hard drive. The important part is that i cant have the images visible in hard drive, they must be encrypted or in an object or something.

So....When i tried to put it in a memory stream and save it to a list and then serialize it down to drive, i got a HUGE program memory allocation because for every image i create,and save as memory stream in my list, i allocate that memory and my program gets over 2-300 mb big.

I really don't have any idea of how to do this, can i somehow save it to memory stream and not allocate that memory in the program? Or can save it some other way without having the pictures totally visible as images in hard drive?

Main thing is as i said, i cant have the images as regular images on hard drive, they must not be able to be viewed by the user without the application. And i need to find a way that don't allocate all computers memory.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file access is built on the principle of *streams*, which can be plug together in a chain. What you can do is, instead of directly reading/writing the images from/to disk through a filestream, you plug a [`CryptoStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx) between it.

Comment: Is this for creating the image as "encrypted" or at least not able to view it without the application?

Comment: @syncis: By saving the image as "encrypted" on the disk it would only be possible to view the file with your application (cause it knows how to decrypt it only).

Comment: Didn't work to make it smaller so this answer was the one that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

> save it to memory stream and not allocate that memory in the program

No. If it's in a memory stream, it is obviously in RAM.

So you need to either store the image entirely in RAM, or save it to disk.

If you don't want it to be viewable on the disk, then you need to encrypt the file so that the user can't view it outside of your application. How heavy the encryption is depends on how hard you want it to be to crack. If you don't care that much, then very basic XOR encryption will be very fast and not increase the size of the file. If you do care, then you want to use something like 3DES.

Comment: That will still make me create all the images file by file to the harddrive, i was hoping to find a way to create like only 1 file and have all the images saved to it, but maybe its impossible? But i will surely check the encryption.

Comment: If you want 1 file with all the images in it, then you can either devise your own format for storing them all, or just shove them all in a ZIP file with a random filename and encrypt that.

Comment: How do you mean devise your own format? Will they be saved in a list in that file? And will this not increase the memory allocation if i have it all in 1 file?

Comment: Just that, decide on a way to store all the images in one big blob. If this isn't something you know how to do then just stuff it in a zip. The amount of memory allocated depends entirely on how much data you're trying to load into RAM so it depends entirely on how well you only keep the images that you're currently working with loaded and the ones you're not using on disk.

Comment: I wont be able to use a zip file because then i wont be able to access the files without unzipping the file first and so on. But i am interested in having all in a big blob, do u have any more info on that? Like how do i save all images to a blob file, and do i have a list with all the images ?

Comment: 'blob' doesn't have any particular meaning. Designing your own file format isn't something that's easy to explain so you're probably best opening another question asking how to store multiple images in a single file in such a way that you can easily access a single one of them.

Comment: I know how to create my own files and have them containing a list, but when i access that file and load the list, it will still allocate all that not needed memory, but if i could somehow create a file, and add the images there, and only use the image that was needed, that would be the solution but that i dont know how =/

Comment: You don't know btw anyone that have asked this question that you are meaning here in stackoverflow ? So i can learn about it.

Comment: You wouldn't load the entire list of images. You'd only load the one you needed at any given time.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to do this? Just hint,no big explanation.
I have searched a bit and people seems to think creating a zip file is one of the best ways to go, but if you could just hint me with the custom file way , maybe i could find the rest my self.

Comment: Just use a streamreader. You'd write a table at the beginning of the file saying which image starts at what position and how long it is, then skip to that position and just read that area.

Comment: Ok but in what do i save it? To a list? As what object? Memorystream?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16493/discussion-between-phonicuk-and-syncis)

Comment: You're needing a far more in depth discussion than is viable via comments. I'll keep this as short as i can: Use something like a streamwriter to build a file that contains an index of all your images, along with all your images. How exactly you do that is something you'll need to figure out. Once you've got an indexed file, you can use a streamreader to only read certain parts of the file.

Comment: I get almost everything, only thing i don't get is how you save the images to a file without making them allocate memory =/

Comment: Depends where the images are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GZIPStream and CryptoStream to make the pictures both smaller and encrypted.

This article shows you exactly how;

http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=33